# how to return a null row using union in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 3 data to be searched in the database.

I need the 3 results to be visible, and the one that has made return null in the query.

I'm using union all to perform the duplicate search, this works.

The question is. I need to get all the data from the survey, even though it's null.

Could anyone get help?

thank you very much for your attention

```
select * from estoques where `si_id` = '02.352' union all select * from estoques where `si_id` = '05.173' union all select * from estoques where `si_id` = '02.305' order by `validade` asc
```

In this example the id 05.173 does not exist in the database.

Expected outcome

```
[
{siaId:'02.352', ...},
{null},
{siaId:'02.305', ...}
]
```

Comment: You would have to display nulls for all columns not just 1 null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join against a derived table:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (
    SELECT '02.352' AS si_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ...
) AS a
LEFT JOIN estoques AS b
    USING (si_id)
ORDER BY a.si_id;
```

You may want to include the id in the output to be able to identify missing rows:

```
SELECT a.si_id, b.*
FROM ...
```

Comment: It worked. There is only one remark. Is it possible for the null row to be in the sequence? thank you so much